# ZIPFoundation in a background thread?

Tags: zipfoundation

Are there any restrictions to using ZIPFoundation in a background thread on iOS (10.0 or later)? I am currently designing an import/export feature for my iOS app and am considering using ZIPFoundation in that feature.

Comment: You'd think the maintainers of an API would handle their own questions instead of telling people to come to SO. Really, why don't you ask _them_? Shouldn't they know? That is, whether you _can_ do something in a queue is different from _how_ you can code such a queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ZIP Foundation leaves threading considerations to the API user. It does not use any queues or locks internally.

The `Archive` class is not re-entrant and therefore cannot be used concurrently from different threads. It's no problem to use the framework on a background thread though. (No main thread-only requirement).

For read operations, you can instantiate multiple `Archive` instances to achieve concurrent reading:
https://github.com/weichsel/ZIPFoundation/issues/29#issuecomment-347139072